# FsUnit won't match exception - F#

Tags: f#, nunit, xunit, fsunit

I am trying to assert an exception using FsUnit built upon XUnit.  I have taken this test from the [FsUnit website](https://fsprojects.github.io/FsUnit/):

```
[<Fact>]
let ``boom`` () =
    (fun () -> failwith "BOOM!" |> ignore) |> should throw typeof<System.Exception>
```

I am using Resharper 2016 to run the test and I get the following error:

```
FsUnit.Xunit+MatchException
Exception of type 'FsUnit.Xunit+MatchException' was thrown.
Expected: System.Exception
Actual:   was SqlJuxtFunctionalTests.Scenarios.CompareTableScenarios+boom@22
   at SqlJuxtFunctionalTests.Scenarios.CompareTableScenarios.boom() in C:\projects\SqlJuxt\src\SqlJuxtFunctional.Tests\CompareTableScenarios.fs:line 22
```

I am using the following versions of the libraries involved:

- FSharp.Core  : 4.0.0.1
- .Net         : 4.6.2
- FsUnit.Xunit : 1.4.1.0
- XUnit.core   : 2.1.0

I thought it might be a problem with XUnit so I tried switching to use FsUnit based on NUnit with the following test:

```
[<Test>]
let ``boom nunit`` () =
    (fun () -> failwith "BOOM!" |> ignore) |> should throw typeof<System.Exception>
```

The NUnit version throws a `MissingMethodException`:

```
System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Void FsUnit.TopLevelOperators.should(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<!!0,!!1>, !!0, System.Object)'.
   at File1.boom()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am at my wits end with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured this out.  To get the test to work I needed to use FsUnit based on NUnit and downgrade FSharp to use FSharp 3.1.2.5.  If you use FsUnit based on NUnit and FSharp 4.0.0.1 then you get the dreaded `MissingMethodException`.

I could not figure out why the code did not work on FsUnit.Xunit.

Comment: Also have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238316/missingmethodexception-when-testing-a-function-that-takes-a-function-parameter/36241071#36241071).